# How to show hidden elements and Scroll to that element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have four forms that is hidden by display none css style and when someone will click on link the respective form should be shown
for e.g

```
<a href="#form1">show form1</a>
<a href="#form2">show form 2</a>
<a href="#form3">show form 3</a>
```

each form has its own unique id

```
form 1  id="form1"  
form 2  id="form2" 
form 3  id="form3"
```

So here is what I've tried

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
$('a[href^="#"]').on('click', function(event) {

    var target = $( $(this).attr('href') );
    var ptel = $(this).attr("href");
    alert(ptel);
    $("#" +ptel).show(); // i tried simply $("ptel")
    if( target.length ) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: target.offset().top
        }, 2000);
    }

});
});
```

when i alert ptel variable it gives me an alert with value of #form1, #form2
but the form is not shown

Comment: your href already has the `#` .. when you do `$("#" +ptel)` is like `##form1`

Comment: ^^ or `target.show();` and get rid of any mention of `ptel`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this line:

```
$("#" +ptel).show(); // i tried simply $("ptel")
```

to

```
$(ptel).show();
```

You don't need to concatenate the `#` and your first attempt was close, but you didn't need the quotes.

Answer (score 0):

you don't need ptel, you can get rid of any mention of it and do this instead

```
target.show();
```